# I can't add transparency for a color v5

Tags: pine-script-v5

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/essential/Colors.html link is not working.
my code :

```
up_col = input.color(#660990, 'Colors',inline='col'), 
dn_col = input.color(#660999, '',inline='col' ),
```

this code is made for v5, but i can't add transparency for v5

https://prnt.sc/21lbtf8

https://prnt.sc/21lbvkb

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code if you want to adjust the transparency from the settings.

````
up_col = input.color(color.new(#660990,0), 'Colors',inline='col')
dn_col = input.color(color.new(#660990,0), '',inline='col' )
trans  =  input.int(0,title="",inline='col',minval=0,maxval=100) 

plot(close,color=color.new(up_col,trans))```
````

Answer (score 0):

To set a color transparency programmatically, you can use the below syntax:

```
colorItem = color.rgb(66, 25, 45, transp = 50)
```

up_col = color.rgb(66, 09, 90, transp = 85)
dn_col = color.rgb(66, 09, 99, transp = 85)

Or you can also use the answer given by Vishnu to give an option to the user to adjust it in the settings.